# What is the default password of 'system' in Jhipster

Tags: jhipster

What's the default password of 'system' in Jhipster? I only have seen the default passwords for admin and user but not the default password for the system. I could not find it in the jhipster docs as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm fairly sure JHipster don't provide this for you. If you really want to gain access to the system account then just create a new user with the password you want. Copy the hashed password for the new user in the database and copy it into the system password part of the .ddl file with the default JHipster accounts defined in it and then rebuild your database.

Comment: Is the system's password not used by the program? I'm thinking if I change it then something might break. The code that uses it might then fail to work.

Comment: No you can change it safely. I have done myself in a project quite recently.

Comment: Thanks! I'll copy the hashed password of the admin instead.

Comment: No problem. If this answer helped you I would really appreciate if you could accept the answer! Good luck with the rest of your project. :)